# Step by step simplification in coq?

Tags: coq

Is there a way to simplify one step at a time?

Say you have `f1 (f2 x)` both of which can be simplified in turn via a single `simpl`, is it possible to simplify `f2 x` as a first step, examine the intermediate result and then simplify `f1`?

Take for example the theorem:

```
Theorem pred_length : forall n : nat, forall l : list nat,
  pred (length (n :: l)) = length l.
Proof.
  intros.
  simpl.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

The `simpl` tactic simplifies `Nat.pred (length (n :: l))` to `length l`. Is there a way to break that into a two step simplification i.e:

```
Nat.pred (length (n :: l)) --> Nat.pred (S (length l)) --> length l
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can also use `simpl` for a specific pattern.

```
Theorem pred_length : forall n : nat, forall l : list nat,
  pred (length (n :: l)) = length l.
Proof.
 intros.
 simpl length.
 simpl pred.
 reflexivity.
Qed.
```

In case you have several occurrences of a pattern like `length` that could be simplified, you can further restrict the outcome of the simplification by giving a position of that occurrence (from left to right), e.g. `simpl length at 1` or `simpl length at 2` for the first or second occurrence.

Comment: That's very useful! But I see that this simplifies all what it is within the pattern. For example `f (g x)` with `simpl f.` will also simplify using `g` definition. Is is possible to instruct coq, in this example case, to just use `f` definition to simplify, and let `g x` as it is?

Answer (score 6):

We can turn simplification for `pred` off, simplify its argument and turn it back on:

```
Theorem pred_length : forall n : nat, forall l : list nat,
  pred (length (n :: l)) = length l.
Proof.
  intros.
  Arguments pred : simpl never.    (* do not unfold pred *)
  simpl.
  Arguments pred : simpl nomatch.  (* unfold if extra simplification is possible *)
  simpl.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

See [§8.7.4](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#Conversion-tactics) of the Reference Manual for more details.

Comment: @Savvas Savvides Thank you for accepting my answer, but let me *respectfully* suggest you not to accept answers too early, since it could discourage some users from providing their own high-quality answers which we are all here interested in. It's better to wait at least 24 hours. Have a nice day and good luck :)