# CoqIde: Show what simpl tactic is doing

Tags: coq, coqide

Using the CoqIde, is there a way to view the steps `simpl` has taken? I find I do not understand how it achieved its result quite often.

Example:

```
rev (rev (n :: l')) = n :: l'
-- apply simpl. 
rev (rev l' ++ [n]) = n :: l'
```

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate of this one -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54047766/how-does-one-inspect-what-more-complicated-tactics-do-in-coq-step-by-step

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one inspect what more complicated tactics do in Coq step-by-step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54047766/how-does-one-inspect-what-more-complicated-tactics-do-in-coq-step-by-step)